# I am learning to write test using jest. I have connected jest to a test DB but regardless of the timeout I set, jest still throws a timeout error

Tags: mongodb, testing, jestjs, automated-tests, phpunit

```
const request = require('supertest');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('../app');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const url = 'mongodb+srv://zenerbogyah7:test1234@cluster0.utpa6al.mongodb.net/';

beforeAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await User.deleteMany({});
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

describe('POST /signup', () => {
  test('should create a new user and return a token', async () => {
    const userData = {
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: 'johndoe@test.com',
      password: 'testpassword',
      passwordConfirm: 'testpassword',
    };

    const response = await request(app).post('/api/signup').send(userData);
    expect(response.status).toBe(201);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('token');
  }, 10000);
});
```

I am trying to test a POST request using Jest and Supertest. The test creates a new user and expects a token to be returned. The test works when the MongoDB database is hosted on the cloud, but when I try to use a local database, the test times out and fails.

This is the error message that I get:

> thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 10000 ms for a test. Add a timeout value
> to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test.
> See [https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout.%22)

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: You are running tests and trying to connect to your remote database. You should connect to your local database instead